# base de datos SQLSERVER

Tags: sql-server-2014

Buen día para todos, necesito realizar un insert en dos tablas a la vez, estas tablas están relacionadas con un cambo id en la tabla uno y es autoincrementable y en la tabla dos esta el mismo cambo (idtabla1) es la foránea, mi pregunta es ¿como hago para que me guarde en la tabla dos el autoincrementable de la tabla uno si no lo conozco y la quiero guardar como una transacción.?

Comment: Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**,  te sugiero modificar tu pregunta, agregar lo que has realizado o investigado, más información, etc, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Bueno intenta realizar estas dos lineas, si los agregas a un procedimiento almacenado mucho mejor:

Insert into tabla1 values (correlativo1.nextval, id);
Insert into tabla2 values (correlativo2.nextval, id,correlativo1.currval);

De esta manera en la tabla2 insertas el valor del correlativo de la tabla1

Saludos